# How can I make a question I no longer care about stop showing up in "inbox" and "notifications"?

Tags: support, questions, notifications, global-inbox

I asked a question that I no longer care about. I cannot delete it because some users have submitted answers. How can I stop messages regarding this question from showing up in my "inbox" and "notifications"?

Comment: You simply can't, without disassociating that question from your account (which isn't recommended, as you'd loose all reputation from the post).

Comment: Of course, if the question was deleted (by 3 20k votes), it would remove the notifications too...

Comment: I doubt I've got much reputation from the question anyhow, to be honest... only one upvote, a few answers submitted but none accepted (one is my own - I didn't accept that either :/ ), and a bunch of comments (but I don't think comments give rep, do they?)...  So...  What is this "disassociating" and what are the implication thereof (besides losing the post's rep)?

Comment: I don't want to pester users to vote or moderators to delete the post unless there are good grounds for doing so... In this, I simply don't care anymore. It was a question of curiosity; nobody's been able to answer it to my satisfaction; I've moved on intellectually. :)

Comment: But is the question so active that you constantly get new notifications?

Comment: You've been a member of SO for a grand total of 12 days. Questions die off. Give it a few days and I'm sure it'll stop bothering you.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, @JoeFrambach...  :)